# Find an Element by .get(index) in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am trying to convert this code from one of my previous projects in Java to C#. Just wondering what is the equivalent to .get(index) in C# for an element?

```
links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(clickOnLinkTab);
```

Full code in Java

```
List<WebElement> li_All = links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for (int i = 0; i < li_All.size(); i++) {

            String clickOnLinkTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
            links_myAccountNav.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(clickOnLinkTab);
            

        } // Opens all the tabs
        Set<String> getTitleinWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = getTitleinWindow.iterator();

        List<String> actualTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
            actualTitleList.add(driver.getTitle());
        }

        return actualTitleList;
```

Comment: If it’s an array or list you access the element at position i by `listname[i]`. If it implements the IEnumerable<> interface you can use`ElementAt(i)`.